# How to use iPython notebook with ngrok

Tags: python, ipython, mathjax, jupyter-notebook

(Maybe better ask on superuser?)
iPython works fine if I use an ssh tunnel.

Using ngrok

iPython notebook loads I get an error about mathjax not loading.

I can enter code into cells but if I try to execute I get no result but the kernel seems to be running. Basically nothing works. I have no idea if I am doing something wrong or if this just wont work.

I am starting starting ngrok like this

```
./ngrok -authtoken myauthtoken 5023
```

and ipython notebook like

```
ipython notebook --no-browser --port=5023
```

Then connect to the iPython session at 
https://mysubdomain.ngrok.com

Comment: Possibly websockets don't work on ngrok? You might want to ask the people behind it.

Comment: You might be right, It's an open source project hosted on github but there does not seem to be a good place to post/ask this. I didn't want to open an issue on github for this.

Comment: https://ngrok.com/ has an 'Ask me a question' thing in the lower right - might be what you're after.

Comment: From Alan at ngrok
"I think this is because ipython notebooks use a web socket connection to update dynamically without refreshing the page. Ngrok doesn't properly tunnel web socket connections yet but I would love to fix that when I have time or accept a patch for that functionality."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Author of ngrok here: ipython notebooks and any other websocket connections now work properly as of ngrok 0.22 which is available at https://ngrok.com/download